# Polyline speed issue while drawing using mouse down, move, and up event

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, polyline

I'm having performance issues while drawing a Polyline using mouse down, move, and up events in C# WPF. Please see code. My code is working fine. The problem which I'm facing is, that when ever I want to draw a continuous line after some time the movement of line become slower. I'd like to know if you have a better solution to draw a line in a faster way or if there is a better solution to improve the existing code.
Thanks.

```
Polyline freeLine;
Point _startPoint;

public void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    freeLine = new Polyline();
    freeLine.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Square;
    freeLine.Stroke = color;
    freeLine.StrokeThickness = thickness;
    canvas.Children.Add(freeLine);
    freeLine.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
}

public void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
    if (_startPoint != currentPoint)
    {
        arrowfreeLine.Points.Add(currentPoint1);
    }
}

public void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    freeLine = null;
}
```

Comment: A couple of pointers: `MouseMove` gets invoked **very** often, consider filtering out a couple of similar points to remove unnecessary detail. Every time you change the points, the Polyline recalculates its entire geometry, maybe draw the Polyline to a WriteableBitmap instead (Or [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) - this one has great performance when you have to draw simple geometries).

Comment: can you please give me a sample code for that

Comment: Which one of the two options? Do you need the complete polyline afterwards? What are you doing with it, etc.. a couple more details are needed to know what you are actually aiming to do.

Comment: First i grab my pc screen then using canvas events i draw lines on picture.which was added in canvas child and on moving mouse add points to line.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my questions - please read my last comment again.

Comment: Which one of the two options.Mean?

Comment: yes i need complete polyline afterwards.

Comment: What more detail you need please let now thanks.

Comment: *"consider filtering out a couple of similar points to remove unnecessary detail"* **or** *"draw the Polyline to a WriteableBitmap instead"*

Comment: if writeablebitmap is used in canvas then give me a small example how to do it otherwise give me example of similar point to remove.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is reduce the number of points by discarding those that are very close to each other. In the example below I remove all points that are within 10 pixels of the previous *significant* point.

```
private Brush _color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
private double _thickness = 4.0;
private int _previousSignificantPoint = 0;
private Polyline _freeLine;

private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Capture mouse
    canvas.CaptureMouse();
    Point startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    _freeLine = new Polyline
    {
        StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Square,
        StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
        Stroke = _color,
        StrokeThickness = _thickness
    };

    // Add first point
    _freeLine.Points.Add(startPoint);

    // make it the first "significant" point
    _previousSignificantPoint = 0;

    canvas.Children.Add(_freeLine);
}

private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure the mouse is pressed and we have a polyline to work with
    if (_freeLine == null) return;
    if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;

    // Get previous significant point to determine distance
    Point previousPoint = _freeLine.Points[_previousSignificantPoint];
    Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    // If we have a new significant point (distance > 10) remove all intermediate points
    if (Distance(currentPoint, previousPoint) > 10)
    {
        for(int i = _freeLine.Points.Count - 1; i > _previousSignificantPoint; i--)
            _freeLine.Points.RemoveAt(i);

        // and set the new point as the latest significant point
        _previousSignificantPoint = _freeLine.Points.Count;
    }

    _freeLine.Points.Add(currentPoint);
}

private void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // release mouse capture
    canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    _freeLine = null;
}

private static double Distance(Point pointA, Point pointB)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pointA.X - pointB.X, 2) + Math.Pow(pointA.Y - pointB.Y, 2));
}
```

Result:

[image: Example result of above code]